# why the integral of a joint function goes from $0$ to $1-x$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, random-variables, density-function

I'm reading the book All of statistics of Larry Wasserman, on the exercise 3.32 is about independent random variables, all seems fine for me, but I can't understand why in the second integral, goes from $0$ to $1-x$, where do we get $1-x$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
x+y\leq 1\implies y\leq 1-x
$$
Combined with the fact that $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$, we can write the domain of integration as $(x,y)$ pairs such that
$$
0\leq y\leq 1-x;\quad \text{and} \quad0\leq x\leq 1.
$$
Here is a picture of the domain of integration shaded in green.
[image: lIntegral Test]

Comment: could be possible get a pairs such?
0≤y≤1−x   and  0≤x≤1-y
due to
x+y≤1⟹x≤1−y